# Detecting a locale-sensitive digit in C

Tags: c, locale, digit

I've been trying to detect whether or not a certain `wchar_t` is considered a digit according to the current locale.

At first, I tried using `iswdigit`, but then I realized it only returns `1` for `0-9`, so it isn't locale-sensitive at all.

Then I tried doing `iswalnum(c) && !isalpha(c)`:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    wchar_t c = L'٠'; // U0660: Arabic-Indic Digit 0
    int len;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("%d\n", iswalnum(c) && !iswalpha(c)); // Prints 1.
    return 0;
}
```

Presumably, this would only be `1` if the character passes the alpha-or-number test but not the number-test. Only problem is, `iswalpha(c)` returns `1` for some mysterious reason.

Which leads me to my question: is there a way to check if a character is a digit in a locale-sensitive way using only standard C or POSIX, without external libraries? Or am I just screwed?

Comment: You might want to look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Classification-of-Wide-Characters.html)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of locale, the only characters the C language permits to be in the `digit` class are the characters `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, ... `'9'` with values `'0'+0`, `'0'+1`, `'0'+2`, ..., `'0'+9`. If you want higher-level semantic information about what might be interpreted as a digit or other numeric form by a human using with cultural conventions matching the locale, you need a much higher-level semantic library.

As for why `iswalnum(c) && !iswalpha(c)` didn't work, the `alnum` class is defined as the union of `alpha` and `digit`. Existing locale authorship practice puts "digits" other than the standard decimal ones in the `alpha` class simply because it's the path of least surprise and at least `alnum` makes sense then.

Comment: A nice terse, yet complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

As R.. already wrote, there is no build-in solution but I remembered that I did it in JavaScript a couple of years ago. A rough one-to-one translation to C:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <wchar.h>
// checks if it is a character resembling a digit
// between 0 (zero) and 9 (nine).
// Numbers (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm)
// are not included.
// Restriction to 16-bit is arbitrary, no digits above at time of writing
// with a range of 0-9 (except e.g.: digits with a full stop or a comma following)
int is_utf16_digit(wchar_t w)
{
  // a small shortcut
  if (isdigit((int)w)) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a bit of range sectioning for legibility
  if (w <= 0x9ef) {
    if (   (w >= 0x0660 && w <= 0x0669)
        || (w >= 0x06f0 && w <= 0x06f9) // EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x0966 && w <= 0x096f) // DEVANAGARI DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x09e6 && w <= 0x09ef) // BENGALI DIGITs
       ) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } else if (w > 0x9ef && w <= 0xc6f) {
    if (   (w >= 0x0a66 && w <= 0x0a6f) // GURMUKHI DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x0ae6 && w <= 0x0aef) // GUJARATI DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x0b66 && w <= 0x0b6f) // ORIYA DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x0be7 && w <= 0x0bef) // TAMIL DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x0c66 && w <= 0x0c6f) // TELUGU DIGITs
       ) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } else if (w > 0xc6f && w <= 0xf29) {
    if (   (w >= 0x0ce6 && w <= 0x0cef) // KANNADA DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x0d66 && w <= 0x0d6f) // MALAYALAM DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x0e50 && w <= 0x0e59) // THAI DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x0ed0 && w <= 0x0ed9) // LAO DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x0f20 && w <= 0x0f29) // TIBETAN DIGITs
       ) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } else if (w > 0xf29 && w <= 0xff19) {
    if (   (w >= 0x1040 && w <= 0x1049) // MYANMAR DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x1369 && w <= 0x1371) // ETHIOPIC DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x17e0 && w <= 0x17e9) // KHMER DIGITs
        || (w >= 0x1810 && w <= 0x1819) // MONGOLIAN DIGITs
/*
  0x2460 - 0x2468 CIRCLED DIGITs 1-9
  0x24ea          CIRCLED DIGITs 0
  0x2474 - 0x247c PARENTHESIZED DIGITs 1-9
  0x2488 - 0x2490 DIGITs 1-9 FULL STOP
  0x24f5 - 0x24fd DOUBLE CIRCLED DIGIT 1-9
  and so on and so forth
*/
        || (w >= 0xff10 && w <= 0xff19) // FULLWIDTH DIGITs (meh?)
/*
  First characters larger than 16 bits:
  (0x10107 - 0x1010f AEGEAN NUMBERs 1-9)
  0x102e1 - 0x102e9 COPTIC EPACT DIGITs 1-9
  0x10a40 - 0x10a43 KHAROSHTHI DIGITs 1-4
  0x10e60 - 0x10e68 RUMI DIGITs 1-9
  Interestingly, the zero for DIGITs 1-9 FULL STOP is at 0x1f100.
  Forgotten by the committee?
  First consecutive digits are the digits with a comma:
  0x1f101 - 0x1f10a
*/
       ) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>   
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  wchar_t *w;

  size_t slen, wlen;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  slen = strlen(argv[1]);
  w = malloc(slen * (sizeof(wchar_t) + 1));
  if (w == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed to allocate %zu bytes\n", slen);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  wlen = mbstowcs(w, argv[1], slen);
  if (wlen == (size_t) - 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "mbstowcs() failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // adjusting memory size with a round of realloc() ommited

  while (*w != L'\0') {
    if (is_utf16_digit(*w)) {
      printf("\"%lc\" (0x%04x) is a digit\n", *w, *w);
    } else {
      printf("\"%lc\" (0x%04x) is not a digit\n", *w, *w);
    }
    w++;
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Example with some characters representing the digit zero from different languages

```
$ ./isutf16digit "asd0asd٠asd೯asd０asd"
"a" (0x0061) is not a digit
"s" (0x0073) is not a digit
"d" (0x0064) is not a digit
"0" (0x0030) is a digit
"a" (0x0061) is not a digit
"s" (0x0073) is not a digit
"d" (0x0064) is not a digit
"٠" (0x0660) is a digit
"a" (0x0061) is not a digit
"s" (0x0073) is not a digit
"d" (0x0064) is not a digit
"೯" (0x0cef) is a digit
"a" (0x0061) is not a digit
"s" (0x0073) is not a digit
"d" (0x0064) is not a digit
"０" (0xff10) is a digit
"a" (0x0061) is not a digit
"s" (0x0073) is not a digit
"d" (0x0064) is not a digit
```

That together with `iswalpha()` should do it but as it is always the case with Unicode and standard-C without a specialized lib: it's doable but it's nasty. See above, for example: the code for testing is quite complicated and it even assumes a lot to keep it simple.